# Показ полной информации в таблице по двойному щелчку

Tags: python, pyqt, таблицы, qtablewidget

У меня есть таблица tableWidget (QTableWidget). Дело в том, что не вся информация помещается в одну строку.
[image: Не помещается текст]

Мне нужно как-то получить информацию из ячейки, на которую пользователь нажал 2 раза

UPD: Я разобрался. Оказывается, у QTableWidget есть метод - `self.tableWidget.cellClicked(self.cell_was_clicked)`

И в этом методе можно найти выделенную ячейку

```
def cell_was_clicked(self, row, column):
    item = self.tableWidget.item(row, column)
    self.id = item.text()
    dlg = DialogGetText(self.id)
    dlg.show()
    dlg.exec()
```

Comment: приведите свой минимальный пример. с нуля писать мало кто захочет

Comment: Как раз дело в том, что я не понимаю, как это можно реализовать. Может вы знаете какие-нибудь методы, позволящие получить всю информацию с определенной строки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите код, который вы уже написали и лучше расскажите что вам надо сделать еще.